# How can I access Laravel facades outside the app folder in a custom class under public folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a legacy PHP class that uses old school SQL queries. This class resides in public/classes/companyProfile/data/MyClass.data.class.php and uses ADONewConnection to run raw SQL queries. It does not have a namespace and that might be the issue.

I would like to use Laravel's facades. Problem is that they do not work.

If I do \DB::table('SomeTable'), it can't find the class. if I try to import as in:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'A facade root has not been set.'

Please note that I have searched stack overflow but I am not clear on a solution. For instance I am using 5.3 and want to use it in the same application in a different class where I am making old sql queries into newer laravel queries.

Many thanks for your assistance in this matter.

The code I inherited:

```
<?

include_once 'accounts/core/DBConn.class.php';
require_once 'classes/core/SomeServiceLoader.php';

/**
 * Class TemplateData
 */
class TemplateData
{
    var $con;

    function someFunction($templateID, $companyID)
    {
// I WANT TO REPLACE THIS WITH LARAVEL STYLE QUERIES
        $sql = <<<SQL
        DELETE
        FROM Templates.SomeData
        WHERE templateID = $templateID
        AND companyID = $companyID
        LIMIT 1
SQL;

        if (! $rs=$this->con->Execute($sql))
        {
            trigger_error ('Some Error: '.$this->con->ErrorMsg().'.'.$sql);
            return false;
        }
        $rs->Close();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I myself, even though I know this isn't an answer to the question directly, would probably spend time moving that code where it should, since _nothing_ in regards to PHP should be in the `public/` folder of a Laravel app save for the assets that Laravel puts there.

Comment: Can you show the code? Is that in your view?

Comment: @aldrin27 I updated my answer above. It is not a view.

Comment: You can try loading the bootstrap file in laravel's bootstrap folder which loads the Laravel classes with autoloader and starts up the Laravel app.